# Provisioning site collections with SharePoint Hosted App

Tags: office-365, site-collection, sharepoint-hosted-app, pnp

I referred to the [Office Dev PnP](http://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP) code on Github to create Site Collection in my O365 environment. This code uses CSOM to create site collections as a provider hosted app hosted on Azure platform. However, is it possible to create a SharePoint Hosted App to do the same job? I take the input like Site Name and URL from the user and create a site collection.

I referred to the [Site Collection Creation](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Provisioning.SiteCollectionCreation) code to create the site collections and the code works just fine.

Comment: check this one http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2014/06/09/provisioning-site-collections-using-sp-app-model-in-on-premises-with-just-csom.aspx

Comment: This is server side code. I wanted a SharePoint Hosted App. JavaScript + HTML.